# Sql vs nosql important data

Tags: database, sql, nosql, scalability

In one of youtubes videos about scalling web sites I found the statement that, however, in term of scallability, noSql is easier and more flexible, though it is better to use SQL for data important enough to not want them be lost (not necessarly secure). Why is so? What mechanism make SQL safer in such term? I'm very VERY beginner with databases so easy answers will be appreciated.

Comment: "NoSQL" is a very broad term.  "SQL" refers to a specfic _language_ that clients use to interact with a DBMS.  It implies certain capabilities, and it requires that data be organized in a specific way.  "NoSQL" literally refers to any data storage system that does not use the SQL language (or, does not _only_ use the SQL language).  Attributes like scalability, reliability, security, etc. depend much more on any given _implementation_ than on any specific access language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what your sources are referring to is [ACID compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). There are lots of SQL databases which provide ACID. Most NoSQL databases, however, do not provide this for the sake of better scalability. The page [What is the relation between SQL, NoSQL, the CAP theorem and ACID?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relation-between-SQL-NoSQL-the-CAP-theorem-and-ACID) on Quora might give you an explanation.

For both categories of databases, however, if one wants data not to get lost, regular backups are important, and that has nothing to do with "SQL" or "NoSql".